# How to generate single insert statement for full table data using SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I have a table with 1,000,000 records in my Oracle Table.

I can use SQL Developer to generate 1,000,000 insert statements as a script.

However to run this script, it takes a lot of time.

Is there any way i can generate 1 single insert statement for all values in the table which when run i know will not take so much time.

Comment: what do you want to do with your script afterwards?

Comment: i want to run the script in another DB so all inserts would be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to create an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
begin
    --add 1 million inserts here
    commit;
end;
/
```

This eliminates almost all of the network round-trips.  It's not the most efficient solution but it's a simple change and is very close to the most efficient solution.

Creating an anonymous block that large may result in an error like `PLS-00123: program too large (Diana nodes)`.  If that happens break the program up into
 smaller chunks and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way i can generate 1 single insert statement for all values in the table which when run i know will not take so much time.

You could use **[INSERT ALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2125362)** statement.

The `INSERT ALL` statement is used to add multiple rows with a single INSERT statement. The rows can be inserted into one table or multiple tables using only one SQL command.

For example,

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (1000, 'IBM')
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (2000, 'Microsoft')
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (3000, 'Google')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

which is equivalent to 3 **INSERT** statements.

Comment: i cannot generate this kind of syntax using SQL Developer. I may have to edit and remove the starting part of the syntax from the 1,000,000 insert statements